# All database items are appearing in each row instead of in their own

Tags: php

I have a form where users can order multiple parts and an email alert is sent with the data. Everything works great, but when there are multiple parts ordered each item appears multiple times. I would like to have each item appear once, on its own line.

This is the PHP that is generating the table:

```
$requestpartnumberarraybr = implode("<br>", $requestpartnumber);
$requestpartdescriptionarraybr = implode("<br>", $requestpartdescription);
$requestpartquantityarraybr = implode("<br>", $requestpartquantity);
$requestpartpricearraybr = implode("<br>", $requestpartprice);
$warehousearraybr = implode("<br>", $warehouse);
$binarraybr = implode("<br>", $bin);
$onhandarraybr = implode("<br>", $onhand);
$availablearraybr = implode("<br>", $available);

foreach($requestpartnumber as $key=>$val) {   
    $message_middle.='
    <tr>
        <td>' . $requestpartnumberarraybr. '</td>
        <td>' . $requestpartdescriptionarraybr . '</td>
        <td>' . $requestpartquantityarraybr. '</td>
        <td>' . $requestpartpricearraybr . '</td>
        <td>' . $warehousearraybr . '</td>
        <td>' . $binarraybr . '</td>
        <td>' . $onhandarraybr . '</td>
        <td>' . $availablearraybr . '</td>                               
    </tr>';
}
```

That code produces this - note that there are multiple items in each row, and then they are repeated:

[image: Table with each item ordered appearing multiple times]

It's supposed to look like this, though, with each item just having one row to itself:

[image: Table with each item having its own row]

Comment: did you see the data? There's an error in the for each line. There are only 3 line items and its producing 9.

Comment: I don't know why you used `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, but you should not be using this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is that you are concatenating every value in the list, and  then for each element in the list you are displaying that concatenated value.

```
//Here you are compressing the array of part numbers into one variable with all the values in the list
$requestpartnumberarraybr = implode("<br>", $requestpartnumber);
...
//Here you loop over each item in the array
foreach($requestpartnumber as $key=>$val) {
...
    //Here, in the loop, you write the variable that has all elements in the array
    '<td align="center" style="border:1px solid black!important;"><font color="black">' . $requestpartnumberarraybr. '</font></td>'
```

So that's why it is happening.

---

As for what to do instead, it seems a little unclear how your information is coming in, but you should be able to simply use `$val` instead of `$requestpartnumberarraybr` when adding to your table variable, and for the other values you should be able to use `$key` on their arrays, like so: `$requestpartdescription[$key]`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for explaining the issue and more importantly providing a solution. I now understand it and know how to fix it.